# What are the recommendations for a Database Design to store crawled info

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm designing a small database to stored all scraped data from some crawlers I have. I scrape the info from some local real state dealers and then clean it and store it in a single table containing all the info but I want change this.

I was thinking of a Multi dimensional model:

Fact Table:

- Properties: Contains all the info of properties (bathroom, bedrooms, etc.)

Dimensions:

- Zones: Contains the districts of the zones
- Currency: Type of Currencies
- Operation type: Sell, rent, etc.
- Property Type: Apartment, house, etc.

This is with the purpose of generating some reports with info like:

- Number of houses
- Price average by zone

I thought this would be the best approach but I was thinking also of making this a NoSQL approach because I don't know anything about NoSQL and thought this could be a project to learn it.

What would be your choice for this and why.

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: This question is too broad - please have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Your design seems no problem to me. For me, there's no need to have Operation and Property dimensions. You can just use fact table to store them.